# Trouble modifying property in superclass from subclass in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop

I'm having a weird problem using object oriented matlab, and I'm not sure if I'm completely missing something, or I've hit some unusual behaviour.
I have a superclass defined as follows:

```
classdef (Abstract) AbstractSimulationData < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
properties (Abstract)
    name
    data
end
properties
    timeStamp = -1
end
methods (Abstract)
    CalculateData(obj, t)
end
methods
    function data = GetData(obj, t)
        if obj.timeStamp == t.t
            data = obj.data;
        else
            obj.timeStamp = t.t;
            obj.CalculateData(t);
            data = obj.data;
        end
    end
end
end
```

When the concrete class implements the method `CalculateData` I intend it to set the superclass property `data`.

Two concrete classes from this are:

```
classdef A < AbstractSimulationData
properties 
    name = 'A'
    data = []
end
methods
    function obj = A
        % No special initialisation
    end
    function CalculateData(obj, t)
        test = t.B.GetData(t)
        obj.data = rand(2,10);
    end
end
end
```

And:

```
classdef B < AbstractSimulationData
properties 
    name = 'B'
    data = containers.Map
end
methods
    function obj = B
        % No special initialisation 
    end
    function CalculateData(obj, t)
        if isempty(obj.data)
            obj.data('left')    = 1;
            obj.data('right')   = 2;
        end
        % Other operations
    end
end
end
```

Within the `A.CalculateData` method I call the `GetData` method for `B`. This in turn calls the `B.CalculateData` method.

Now, as it filters back up, the `data` property gets set correctly so that `B.GetData` returns the value that was set in `B.CalculateData`.
But, when I go the next step up to `A.GetData` it returns `[]`, the initialised value. Going through debug mode, the calculations definitely work in `A.CalculateData` and it seems to set `data` correctly, but when it jumps back up to the superclass `obj.data` is *the default value from `A`*.

A minimum working example to get this behaviour:

```
t.B = B();
t.t = 1;

a = A;

a.GetData(t);

>> test = 
Map with properties:

    Count: 2
  KeyType: char
ValueType: any

>> ans = 
[]
```

This is all part of a pretty big project, so it's hard to give the full context, but if it's possible from this, can someone explain why setting superclass `data` works for `B` but not `A`?
If it makes a difference `B` is returning a `container.Map` and `A` is returning 2xn matrix.

As far as I can tell from [the documentation](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modify-superclass-properties.html), it should work.

Comment: As a side note, I managed to work around the problem by making `CalculateData` return the data, then set it directly in the superclass, but I'd still like to know what went wrong in the original way

Comment: The flow of data is pretty confusing here, I'm not surprised it's tripping up somewhere. You might be able to simplify this with [dependent properties](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html), then `get.data` would be a function which is implicitly called when accessing the `data` attribute of your class. Then `A`can just use `B.data` and not have any concern how that is generated (i.e. using `GenerateData` or otherwise).

Comment: That might be a nicer way out of it. I keep forgetting matlab has the setter and getter accessing like that

Comment: I've added a minimum working example now

Comment: Do you use the MATLAB Editor? I recommend that you do. And I recommend that you look at each of the squiggly red underlines, they're issues that the linter finds with your code. In this case, the `CalculateData` function for class `A` has `obj.data = ...` highlighted as a problem. It tells me that for value classes, a method that modifies the object must return the object. In short, in MATLAB you generally do `a = CalculateData(a)`, not `a.CalculateData()`. The latter form is only valid for handle classes; you need to have your class inherit from `handle`.

Comment: Read here for the difference between the two class types: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html -- And here for when to use each type of class: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/which-kind-of-class-to-use.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo Forgive my ignorance but I thought by doing `< matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` handle was included? And given your explanation, I can't see why it works in `B` but not `A`

Comment: As an update switching from `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` to `handle` fixes everything (I didn't really need `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` here), but I'm still baffled as to why the code above produces the given output